# Counting filtered expression

Tags: angularjs, filter

In AngularJS, I would like to show a counter that shows "done/all" tasks for each of the below groups, i.e. in this case :

```
food:       1/2
hygienics:  0/1
```

List of tasks:

```
$tasks = [
    {
        title:  "buy bacon",
        group: "food",
        done:   "true",
    },
    {
        title:  "buy tuna",
        group: "food",
        done:   "false",
    },
    {
        title:  "buy toothpaste",
        group:  "hygienics",
        done:   "false",
    },
];
```

The counter should automatically update whenever I set a task's "done" to "true". So really, I am looking for a nice filtered expression, like the following (but with "done" worked in):

```
Food: {{ ( tasks | filter: {group:'food'} ).length }}
```

How can I include "done" into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.using_filters):

> You can chain filters using this syntax:

```
{{ expression | filter1 | filter2 }}
```

so just chain an additional filter:

```
tasks | filter: {group:'food'} | filter: {done: true}
```

Or, still from [the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter)

> expression – {string|Object|function()} –
>
> The predicate to be used for selecting items from array.
>
> Can be one of:

[...]

> Object: A pattern object can be used to filter specific properties on objects contained by array. For example {name:"M", phone:"1"} predicate will return an array of items which have property name containing "M" and property phone containing "1".

So you could also use

```
tasks | filter: {group:'food', done: true}
```

Not tested, though.

Comment: Thanks, wouldn't have guessed that it'd be this easy :)